# Crear registro si no existe en la tabla o actualizar datos si existiera el registro

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Necesito guardar los datos en una tabla si estos no existen aún o actualizarlos si estos existieran. Tengo este código hasta el momento que solo los crea en la tabla, la tabla se llama Coin.php

```
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/',
        'timeout'  => 2.0,
    ]);
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'ticker');

    $coins = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    foreach ($coins as $res) {
        $datos = new Coin;
        $datos->name = $res->name;
        $datos->symbol = $res->symbol;
        $datos->rank = $res->rank;
        $datos->save();
    }
```

Este método es un comando que se ejecuta cada 5 minutos y tiene que revisar si existen o no en la tabla para poder hacer las operaciones que comento mas arriba.

Estoy ocupando Laravel 5,6 
Alguna idea?

Comment: Veo que intentas guardar 3 propiedades de dicha instancia, sin embargo, en caso que encuentre algún modelo que conocida, ¿qué valores debe actualizar?

Comment: Esos mismo valores, name, symbol y rank. Hay veces que las cryptodivisas cambian de nombre, y por consecuencia cambian de símbolo, también cambian de ranking. Como comentaba, si existe que se actualice el dato, si no existe, que se cree un nuevo registro. Como logro esto en laravel? soy nuevo en este framework

Comment: Lo que pasa es que necesitas pasar valores de comprobación para ver si existe o no un valor, ejemplo si existe tal nombre, entonces actualizar el rank o el símbolo, de lo contrario ¿Cómo podría saber Laravel que ya existe dicho registro?

Comment: Quizás declarando un $datos = Coin::all() y luego dentro de un foreach saber si el nombre de lo que existe en datos corresponde al nombre que trae la consulta la api, si existe actualizar, de lo contrario, agregar

Comment: Creo que no me estoy haciendo entender, si por algún motivo los 3 valores cambian, no sabríamos que registro actualizar, ¿o nunca cambia el nombre?

Comment: Claro, tienes razón ahí, quizás almacenar el ID de esos datos que vienen de la api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas crear un registro o actualizarlo, puedes usar updateOrCreate(), cuyo primer parámetro son los valores con los que compruebas si el registro existe o no, y el segundo parámetro son los valores que serán actualizados. En caso que el registro no exista, este se creará con los valores proporcionados en el primer y segundo parámetro.

Como ejemplo voy a suponer que con "name" verificamos si existe o no el registro:

```
Coin::updateOrCreate(
    ['name' => $res->name],
    ['symbol' => $res->symbol, 'name' => $res->rank]
);
```

Con este método no necesitas llamar el método save().

Para más información puedes revisar la documentación de Eloquent, en la sección Other creation methods.

Comment: Te pasaste! funciona perfecto, hice algunos arreglos también en la tabla y todo anda de lujo